# Powershell Nuget push command URL contains space

Tags: powershell, command, nuget, push, space

During nuget packet publishing I got the error:

The specified source '\\fileserver\IT User Data\Nuget' is invalid. Please provide a valid source.

The problem must be related to spaces in source URL. Any experience of problem-solving?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the URL in a variable, e.g. $SitePath, then use the [uri]::EscapaeDataString() method.

```
[uri]::EscapeDataString($SitePath)
```